# Git checkout --patch

Tags: git, github, cmd

I want to get the patch started and not apply it fully so that the user can open up their IDE of choice and manually walk through the merge conflicts.

This command: `git checkout --patch branch path/to/file` allows me to merge in the changes of just one file. I am missing something though because it forces the terminal to become interactive and need answers on each hunk/patch.

How do I force this command it not ask questions and just allow me to resolve the conflicts elsewhere?

Comment: You don't. You would use a different command (`git apply -3`) for that; to run `git apply -3` you'll first need to *prepare* the patch to be applied. Note, however, that an explicit `git checkout --patch branch path/to/file` won't have merge conflicts in the first place: the diff is between the working tree copy and the specified copy, and each hunk *in* that diff will apply cleanly. (When all are applied, the result is the file as it appears in the specified commit.) So there's something missing from your question here.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the `yes` command into the `git` command:

```
yes | git checkout --patch branch path/to/file
```